# Laptop "thinks" it's overheating, shuts down itself

Tags: cpu, shutdown, fan, cooling

*Short version:* When I turn on the laptop fans go full speed even though the the laptop is ice cold. After about 20 seconds it shuts down itself which I guess it's "*thinking*" CPU is overheating.

*Long version:* Recently I had an overheating issue with it, I thought open it up and clean the fan. I knew the problem was with the fan because I did not do any heavy tasks with this laptop which would need a lot of resources to compute and the fan didn't seem to push any air out from the air vents.

Now this is not my first time opening my laptop so it wasn't hard, I follow the disassembly video just to make sure I would not forget anything. I open it open clear the dusts stuck in the fan which was a lot. The vents were completely clear. I assembled the laptop again, turned it on, it was on for a couple of minutes and then it shuts down. The problem seemed to be the battery since it only lasts for 5 minutes. I connected the charger and turned it on again. In the middle of boot up it shuts down. The strange thing is fans are working full speed the whole time even though it's cold.

I am pretty sure I have connected everything. But of course there's something I have missed which causes this problem. I did not disassemble the heatsink from CPU. I only opened the fan.

What could be the problem

Comment: There is probably a problem between the CPU and the heatsink (a bronzey coloured pipe that attaches to the CPU using some thermal paste or a thermal paste "pad"). This may have become detached or has "worn"/"dried up". By "worn" the conductive properties of the paste or pad change over a period of time due to the heat created by the CPU. The CPU notifies the motherboard that it needs more cooling -> the fans come on -> the CPU still says it needs more cooling -> the fans speed up -> the CPU still isn't being cooled -> it shuts itself off in panic.

Comment: You may have cooked it - permanently.

Comment: @BigChris As I said, the heatsink was not detached I just detached the fan from the heatsink but it still was connected to CPU. The other thing is, I do not think that the CPU has that much high temperature at 20 seconds into the boot up. The laptop was ice cold.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 How do you mean?

Comment: Over time the paste or pad can dry up, regardless of whether it has been dismantled or not. Trust us, we've been doing this for years... You may not necessarily have done any permanent damage, but it is worth re-pasting or padding the thermal compound between the CPU and heatsink.

Comment: I actually meant the hardware. The constant overheats DO cause damage, even if it shuts itself down.  I've seen that as the answer in this scenario _way_ more times than bad thermal paste (like 99:1). But of course it's always worth carefully striping down, examining and re-attaching the heat-sink apparatus (with a dab of new paste), since its so cheap to do and may be the cause (bad paste, heat-pipe fractures, etc.).  But that's just from my experience.

Answer (score 1):

I opened up the laptop again. Problem was that the I had loosened up one of the four screws that connect heatsink to the CPU and forgot to tighten it up. This caused the fan go crazy and the CPU shut itself down in order to prevent overheating.